# Handling dynamically changing element id - using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dopostback

I m having the login page, when click login button it opens the new tab.

i moved the control to new window using,

```
driver.switchTo().window("_blank");
```

When I click one `Button` it will open the new popup (that popup is not a normal window it is a iframe).

I have selected a popup window using,

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frameName");
```

That popup has the list of records; each record has the separate "select" option (with the dynamically changing id's).

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='radgrdPeople_ctl00_ctl04_lnkSelect']")).click();
```

When selecting the record from list, the popup window will be closed and the page will get refreshed.

Now I want to return the control to my parent window for doing some other stuff.

The record got selected successfully. But i could not able to focus the parent window again.

I have tried:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultcontent();
driver.switchTo().window("_blank");
```

And

```
driver.getWindowHandles()
```

Still I m getting the same problem.

I don't know whether I have to use any java script executor for handling the dynamically changing element id's.

Could u any one please help me on this....

Thanks in Advance.

By 
K.Ranjithkumar

Answer (score 0):

In the post after clicking the login button you used `WindowName` to switch over to the new window. But, in the tried solution, you used `empty string` to switch over to the new window.

Answer (score 0):

You should make first window as parent window

```
String parent=driver.getwindowhandle;
// then, set String popup to be equal to window handle of the 
// popup window
driver.switchTo().window( popup);
driver.findElement(By.id("okbutton")).click(); //assumes close of popup
```

Now after performing tasks on popup window, return control to parent window:

```
driver.switchTo().window( parent );// switch back to parent window
driver.switchTo().defaultcontent(); // reset iframe context
```